# Facing Status code 401 in supabase okta authentication with next.js

Tags: next.js, access-token, saml-2.0, okta, supabase

i manage OKTA SSO Authentcation using supabase in a Next.js App

**Problem:** When i successfully sso Sign in i got access token as fragment identifier
localhost:3000/#accessToken=xyz

i got in the console error of
*Having user null AuthApiError: invalid claim: missing sub claim*

**This is The sign-in route logic file**

```
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url)
  const formData = await request.formData()
  const email = String(formData.get('email'))
  const password = String(formData.get('password'))
  const domain = String(formData.get('domain'))
  const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies })
  // const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
  //   email: email,
  //   password: password,
  // })

  const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithSSO({
    domain: domain
  })
  console.log(requestUrl);

  if (data?.url) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(
        data.url,
        {
          // a 301 status is required to redirect from a POST to a GET route
          status: 301,
        }
      )
  }
  localStorage.setItem('accessToken', `Bearer ${String(supabase.realtime.accessToken)}`)

  if (error) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      `${requestUrl.origin}/login?error=Could not authenticate user`,
      {
        // a 301 status is required to redirect from a POST to a GET route
        status: 301,
      }
    )
  }
  return NextResponse.redirect(requestUrl.origin, {
    // a 301 status is required to redirect from a POST to a GET route
    status: 301,
  })
}
```

**Here How I Suppose To Get The User**

```
  const supabase = createServerComponentClient({ cookies })

  const {
    data: { user }, error
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser()
```

[SSO_NextJS.zip](https://ufile.io/gqks05o2)